# What is wrong with this SQL Query in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

Trying to run this SQL Query and although it says it was executed successfully, it does not return 1 result.  Instead, it returns all rows from the database table as it normally does:

```
SELECT * FROM [Philadelphia].[dbo].[mmgusers_tbl] [WHERE UserName = 'testing' LIMIT 1];
```

How do I change this to give me only 1 row when executed?

Comment: Please do not use select *. Explicitly specify the output as this will have an impact on execution.

Comment: `LIMIT 1` is MySql syntax. The equivalent in MS SQL Server is `TOP 1` following your 'SELECT' like so. `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Philadelphia].[dbo].[mmgusers_tbl] WHERE UserName = 'testing'`

Comment: You shouldn't be putting the *whole* `where` clause between those dreaded brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LIMIT 1 is used in mySQL to limit records. In SQL Server, try using the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Philadelphia].[dbo].[mmgusers_tbl] WHERE UserName = 'testing';
```

Comment: Getting this error:  `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near ']'.`

Comment: Check your syntax to make sure that you do not have an extra square bracket somewhere. This syntax works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Top 1 * FROM [Philadelphia].[dbo].[mmgusers_tbl] 
WHERE UserName = 'testing'
```

**(Or)**

```
Select * FROM
(
SELECT *,Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)) AS RN FROM [Philadelphia].[dbo].[mmgusers_tbl]  WHERE UserName = 'testing' 
) AS T
Where RN = 1
```

Comment: The square brackets are used on the [database]/[type]/[tablename]. You do not need to include them on the rest of the statement. It really helps when if bad naming conventions are made such as [Username.DatabaseX].[dbo].[Tablename]

Comment: I'm confused about that second SQL query. LIMIT isn't part of the SQL Server syntax, that query will throw an error.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Please check now

Comment: @VigneshKumar Not sure what I'm supposed to be checking. You're still using LIMIT in the second query, which isn't valid SQL Server syntax. Just remove that entire second query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what your looking for

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Philadelphia].[dbo].[mmgusers_tbl] WHERE UserName = 'testing';
```

Comment: Putting `[` and `]` around the WHERE clause means that's an alias for the table, not an actual WHERE clause.

Comment: `[WHERE UserName = 'testing'];` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM [Philadelphia].[dbo].[mmgusers_tbl] WHERE UserName = 'testing'
```

and only 1 rows matched a UserName of 'testing'

if you just want a single row

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Philadelphia].[dbo].[mmgusers_tbl] WHERE UserName = 'testing'
```